# BackButton Windows Phone 8 (VB)

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, back-button

I have a Program with 2 Frames ("MainPage" and "Inicio", "Inicio" is the first one on be opened).

"Inicio" Has a Link to open "MainPage" and, when the user is on "MainPage", I want to make an event that when the BackButton (the <- of the phone) is pressed, the Program go back to "Inicio", but instead of it, the program is suspended and the Phone go back to the Windows Home.

I'm working on VB and I can't find any tutorial or Event to VB, all that I found on google was to C# and I don't know how to convert code from C# to VB for now.

Please Note that I'm working with VB for Metro (Or VB For App Store) and I had to  define the event on the XAML, and there is the problem, because, not like when we code on .VB, I don't have suggestion or error marks. I can write "aigwiuagwa_aiuwdaiu as Handler..." and for the builder that Event exists.

Comment: [Events (Visual Basic)...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to said that I'm working with VB for Metro (or VB For App Stores), and it doesn't has the same events and controllers as VB.Net, VB6, or whatever you want to call the traditional VB. So, the classic Button_click (and that is not the thing that I want for, I want to make an event that detects when the Hardware BackButton is pressed to go back to the "Inicio" frame instead of close the app) doesn't exist until I define it on the Frame design's XAML Code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was ussing "Blank Page", and I needed to use "Normal Page". "Normal Page" has Navigation Helper that detects if there is another Page/Frame to go back or not. Another thing is that NavigationHelper has a lot of "#IF WINDOWS_PHONE_APP Then" and it doesn't detects that it is actually an Windows Phone Apps, so the Back Button doesn't works either. The solution was to Delete that IF, and below of then is allways an "ElseIf", the thing is to replace that "ElseIf" with "#IF WINDOWS_APP then". I needed to do it 3 times. Now my app is working fine.